# Is there a way to see Scipy.Special.Gamma() function implementation in the source?

Tags: python, scipy, implementation, gamma-function

I've tried to  write functions to calculate special functions (e.g. exponential, gamma, erf, etc), but to do the sum or product operations, I used while-loop with 10k turns. This is very time-consuming.

Then, I realized that scipy.special.gamma() function is significantly faster than my while-loop and I wanted to see and study the implementation/algorithm of the gamma function, but I couldn't find the source codes on the internet.

Is there a way to see the source codes of Scipy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SciPy's source code is hosted on GitHub here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy

For floating-point arguments, SciPy uses [CEPHES's](https://www.netlib.org/cephes/) implementation of gamma: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/special/cephes/gamma.c

For complex arguments, SciPy uses a Cython implementation: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/special/_loggamma.pxd